# javascript code to differentiate between ipad and ipad retina?

Tags: javascript, ipad, ipad-3

I'm developing an application for Ipad. So I need to change the image rendering depending upon the devide wheteher it is  ipad or ipad-retina . So can anybody tell me how to detect the difference between ipad and ipad-retina?  Thanx!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var isRetina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1;
```

Check this out: [**Detect retina displays with javascript**](http://briancray.com/posts/detect-retina-displays-with-javascript).

Comment: be sure to check that code in both orientations - ISTR that the pixel ratio changes for landscape vs portrait.

Answer (score 0):

```
var retina = (window.retina || window.devicePixelRatio > 1);
```

Resource: http://hjzhao.blogspot.in/2012/07/detect-retina-display-using-javascript.html

Also use Modernizr

https://github.com/benlister/utilities/tree/master/Modernizr%20Retina%20:%20HiDPI%20test

Comment: what is `window.retina`?  Seems like a non-standard (or even non-existent) property to me.